# Putting a String from a text into an array, using scanf

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I'm having some problems reading a string into an array. my file contains the following strings running horizontally down the page.

**File**:

```
dog
cat
rabbit
mouse
```

**Code**:

```
#include <string>
int i = 0;
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    FILE * input1;
    fopen_s(&input1, "C:\\Desktop\\test.dat", "r");
    string test_string;
    while (!feof(input1)) {
        fscanf_s(input1, "%s", test_string);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any advice would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Where is your array?

Comment: Why don't you use **C**, if you want to write such code?

Comment: `test_string.data()` will allow you to use your string inside `fscanf_s`. But take care to reserve some memory with `test_string.resize(...)`. And take a look at `fstream` and `getline` which are "more" C++

Comment: Counter question why don't you use c++, `std::ifstream` and `std::getline()`?

Comment: And if I understand well, you want `test_string` to be put inside an array. So take a look at `vector` or `list` or any other modern container

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone. @Sumeet I thought the array was was created using string test_string; (line 8).

Comment: Thanks @Garf365 , I was trying to make test_string my array to store my values in.

Comment: Doesn't the fopen_s need a pointer to FILE ... _FILE *_  ?

Comment: No, line 8 doesn't create an array. It just create a string. replace by `std::vector<std::string> test_strings` and use it like `test_string[i]` to get _i_ th string

Comment: I see, would line 10 then become   `fscanf_s(input1, "%s", test_string[i]);` ?@Garf365

Comment: Not totally, maybe I make a misteak, but for me, `fscanf_s` doesn't accept a string as parameter. You have to use `test_string[i].data()` or `&test_string[i][0]` *and* before resize to allocate memory (`test_string[i].resize(50)` to reserve 50 characters). After `fscanf_s` you have to resize with correct size (`test_string[i].resize(strlen(test_string[i].c_str()));`. But to avoid all this laborious steps, consider to use `ifstream` and `getline` instead of `fopen` and `fscanf_s`

Comment: Is there really a need to use `fscanf`? Can't you simply use `ifstream` and `getline`?

Comment: The only reason I used fscanf is because i'm familiar with the expression.

Comment: Without going into "why write such code?" ...  1)  include the stdio.h  2) use  _input1=fopen("test.txt", "r");_ 3) use _char test_string[1024]_ instead of _string_ 4) use _fscanf(input1, "%s", test_string);_ 5) In the end print the counter _i_ (I assume you were trying to count lines?) 6) Use compiler warnings extensively (something like _-Wall_)

Comment: Then you should get familiar with [`fstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/)

Comment: See: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/253056)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`ifstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/) and [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Now, I'm going to walk you through reading lines from the file using `ifstream`

Include `fstream` to use `ifstream`.

```
#include <fstream>
```

**Opening a file**:

To open a file, create an object of `ifstream`, and call it's method `open` and pass the filename as parameter. `ifstream` opens a file to read from it. (To write in a file, you can use [`ofstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/))

```
ifstream fin;
fin.open("C:\\Desktop\\test.dat");
```

Or you can simply pass the filename to the constructor to create an object of `ifstream` and open a file.

```
ifstream fin("C:\\Desktop\\test.dat");
```

**Reading from the file**:

You can use stream extraction operator (`>>`) to read from the file, just like you use `cin`

```
int a;
fin >> a;
```

To read a *line* from a file using the above created `fin` (using a `char` array)

```
char arr[100];
fin.getline(arr, 100);
```

Better yet, you should use `std::string` instead or `char` arrays, using `std::string`, you can read a line using `std::getline`

```
string testString;
getline(fin, testString);
```

---

Now, let's change your code to use `ifstream` and `getline`

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    ifstream input1;
    input1.open("C:\\Desktop\\test.dat");
    string test_string;

    while (getline(input1, test_string)) {
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! does `fin` and `cin` work with C++ or just C?

Comment: They're **NOT** for C, they're just for C++.